# Multi-threaded Time Scheduler without polling

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, timer, singleton

This is a quick shot at designing a time scheduler without polling. It is able to handle inputs which are to be executed earlier than already on the schedule. I want to improve it further, especially my `insert()` as I find the implementation rather ugly. Wish I could simplify it using condition_variable::wait_for().

The Scheduler is designed as a Singleton for my personal needs. The time-bots are launched to trigger the actual events, but they can be ejected if required.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>
#include <condition_variable>


typedef std::function<void(void)> task_t;
typedef std::chrono::system_clock::time_point time_point;
std::map<time_point, task_t> schedules_;

class time_bot; // forward declaration

class scheduler
{
private:
    std::map<time_point, task_t> schedules_;
    std::condition_variable signal_;
    std::mutex lock_;
    std::unique_ptr<time_bot> time_bot_;
    bool running_;
    bool trigger_ready_;
    std::thread* thread_;
private:
    scheduler(scheduler&&) = delete;
    scheduler(const scheduler&) = delete;
    scheduler& operator()(scheduler&&) = delete;
    scheduler& operator()(const scheduler&) = delete;
    scheduler();
    void run();

public:
    static const std::unique_ptr<scheduler>& get_instance();
    void insert(std::pair<time_point, task_t> node);
    void remove(time_point tp);
    void close();
    void executed(time_point tp);
    ~scheduler();
};

class time_bot
{
private:
    std::pair<time_point, task_t>  task_;
    bool wasted_;
    std::thread* thread_;
    std::condition_variable& signal_;
    bool& trigger_ready_;
public:
    time_bot(std::pair<time_point, task_t> task, std::condition_variable& signal, bool& trigger_ready)
        :task_(task),
        signal_(signal)
        , trigger_ready_(trigger_ready)
    {
        trigger_ready = false;
        wasted_ = false;
        thread_ = new std::thread([&]() { run(); });
    }
    ~time_bot()
    {
        if (wasted_)
        {
            std::cout << " A wasted time_capsule destroyed. \n";
            thread_->join();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << " A time_capsule destroyed after sucessful trigger. \n";
            thread_->join();
        }

    }

    std::pair<time_point, task_t> get() const
    {
        return task_;
    }

    void set_wasted()
    {
        wasted_ = true;
    }
    void run()
    {
        std::cout << " A timed-task std::thread started \n";
        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto lapse = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(task_.first - now);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(lapse));
        if (!wasted_)
        {
            task_.second();
            scheduler::get_instance()->executed(task_.first);
            std::cout << " A timed-task executed \n";
        }

    }
};



scheduler::scheduler()
{
    time_bot_ = nullptr;
    trigger_ready_ = false;
    running_ = true;
    thread_ = new std::thread([&]() { run(); });
}


scheduler::~scheduler()
{
    thread_->join();
    std::cout << "Scheduler std::thread joined successfully \n";
}

void scheduler::run()
{
    std::cout << "Scheduler std::thread initialized  \n";
    while (running_)
    {
        if (!schedules_.empty())
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(lock_);
            signal_.wait(lock, [&]() {return trigger_ready_ || !running_; });
            if (!running_) return;
            time_bot_.reset(new time_bot(*schedules_.begin(), signal_, trigger_ready_));
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}

const std::unique_ptr<scheduler>& scheduler::get_instance()
{
    static std::unique_ptr<scheduler> ptr;
    if (ptr == nullptr)
        ptr.reset(new scheduler());
    return ptr;
}

void scheduler::insert(std::pair<time_point, task_t> node)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(lock_);

    auto ready_trigger = [&]()
    {
        if (time_bot_ == nullptr)
        {
            trigger_ready_ = true;
            signal_.notify_one();
        }
    };

    if (schedules_.empty() && time_bot_ == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "node entered [schedules_.empty() && time_bot_ == nullptr ]  \n";
        schedules_.insert(node);
        ready_trigger();
    }
    else
        if (time_bot_ == nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "node entered [time_bot_ == nullptr]  \n";
            schedules_.insert(node);
        }
        else
            if (time_bot_ != nullptr)
            {
                if (time_bot_.get()->get().first < node.first)
                {
                    std::cout << "node entered [node.first]  \n";
                    schedules_.insert(node);
                }
                else
                {
                    time_bot_->set_wasted();
                    time_bot_.reset();
                    schedules_.insert(node);
                    std::cout << "node entered [Prev marked wasted]  \n";
                    ready_trigger();
                }
            }

    lock.unlock();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
}
void scheduler::executed(time_point tp)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(lock_);
    auto it = schedules_.find(tp);
    if (it != schedules_.end())
        schedules_.erase(it);
    if (!schedules_.empty())
    {
        trigger_ready_ = true;
        signal_.notify_one();
    }
}

void scheduler::remove(time_point tp)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(lock_);
    auto it = schedules_.find(tp);
    if (it != schedules_.end() && it != schedules_.begin())
        schedules_.erase(it);
}
void scheduler::close()
{
    running_ = false;
    signal_.notify_one();
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    std::cout << " Enter test# (1,2,3) ? ";
    std::cin >> i;
    switch (i)
    {
    case 1:
        scheduler::get_instance()->insert(make_pair(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(1), []() { std::cout << " Task[quick first] \n"; }));
        scheduler::get_instance()->insert(make_pair(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(2), []() { std::cout << " Task[Slow second] \n"; }));
        break;
    case 2:
        scheduler::get_instance()->insert(make_pair(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(3), []() { std::cout << " Task[Slow first] \n"; }));
        scheduler::get_instance()->insert(make_pair(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(1), []() { std::cout << " Task[Impatience second] \n"; }));
        break;
    default:
        scheduler::get_instance()->insert(make_pair(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(3), []() { std::cout << " Task[Slow first] \n"; }));
        scheduler::get_instance()->insert(make_pair(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(1), []() { std::cout << " Task[Medium second] \n"; }));
        scheduler::get_instance()->insert(make_pair(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(2), []() { std::cout << " Task[Impatience third] \n"; }));
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
    scheduler::get_instance()->close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Concerning 1201ProgramAlarm’s first sentence, see [Standard Guideline C.149](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c149-use-unique_ptr-or-shared_ptr-to-avoid-forgetting-to-delete-objects-created-using-new).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You leak memory in various places, particularly the `thread` objects you create.  They're allocated with `new`, and joined, but never deleted.

You have a global `schedules_` variable that is never used, since all the code references are within the `scheduler` class and will use the member variable.  Since you have your main loop in `scheduler::run` accessing the `schedules_` variable (the call to `schedules_.empty()`) outside of a lock, you have a race condition since another thread can be modifying the map while this check is occurring.

`scheduler::run` is also not very power friendly if there is nothing to schedule, since it uses a polling loop to check for a new task.  This should use something like `std::condition_variable` to stay dormant until it is notified that a new task is available.

`scheduler::get_instance` is also not thread safe, since if two threads call it simultaneously before the instance is created, you'll get multiple instances.  Since C++ now guarantees thread safety for initialization of static variables, just use a static instance of `scheduler` and dispense with the dynamic allocation.  If you must use the dynamic allocation, you need to use something like a mutex to ensure you only create one instance of `scheduler`.

Within `scheduler::insert` itself, you have multi-line `else` statements that do not have enclosing curly braces.  While not necessary, having them in will make the code a bit easier to follow while reducing the chance of somebody making an edit later that changes the flow.

The `default` in the switch in `main` is lacking a `break` statement.  Although not currently necessary (since the default is the last branch in the switch), you should always include the `break`.  Otherwise when somebody comes along and adds another case after the `default` the missing `break` will cause problems.